# fopen() error handling

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm working on a script at the moment that reads in an `HTML` template file, populates it with data and then saves the populated `HTML` file as a cached copy in my cache folder.

I'm having real difficulties evaluating whether an error has occured with `fopen()` while runtime errors are suppressed:

```
$file = @fopen($location,"w+"); 

// manual states fopen() returns false on error
// though the below does not catch any errors 

if (!$file) {
    $this->doSomething();
}
```

Is the suppression working against me? I would really appreciate some insight into this. I have tried setting `error_reporting` to display no errors,

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and removed the supression from `fopen()` but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code should work. If you never enter the `if` statement and no errors are triggered, the file was opened successfully. Why are you sure that the `fopen()` call failed?

Comment: I deliberately set it up to fail with a bogus $location to test for an error but nothing... maybe I need to take a look at my PHP ini file. Thanks for looking into it Dave.

Comment: Bear in mind that when you open a file in `w+` mode, it will create the file if it doesn't exist, so may not actually fail. Try it with a bogus location and `r` or `r+` and it will fail, or try and open a file in directory that doesn't exist and it will fail. There are no ini settings to control this behaviour that I know of - if you are still having issues when you are doing something that 100% certain shouldn't work, there is something (very odd) wrong with your PHP install...

Comment: Thanks Dave, I used r+ and indeed it started to fail. I then noticed that the file had been created with w+ in my root directory. Thanks for pointing this out and helping!